# How to write a quad into a jena graph and then to file

Tags: rdf, jena, semantic-web

I want to create a Quadruple like `PersonA isIn RoomA atTime 12:00`. I want to use for atTime the `System.current.TimeStamp()`.

I tried to create a quad by:

```
Node roomA_Node = NodeFactory.createURI(((Resource) roomA).getURI());
Node person1_Node = NodeFactory.createURI(((Resource) person1).getURI());
Node isin_node = NodeFactory.createURI(((Resource) ROOM_STREAM.isIn).getURI());
Node timestamp = NodeFactory.createLiteral("2001-10-26T21:32:52",
        XSDDatatype.XSDdateTime);

Quad q = new Quad(timestamp, person1_Node, isin_node, roomA_Node);
```

However, now I am stuck, because I would like to write it to a `TTL`(or sth similar) file?

Any suggestions how to do that?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: I think you may misunderstand what a quad is.  A quad isn't a "four place relation" or a "statement with subject, predicate, object, and time/indirect object/something else".  A quad is a triple and a graph name.  Datasets can have named graphs that contain triples, so you need a quad to record the triple and the graph in which is appeared.

Comment: It sounds much more like you just want an n-ary relation, in which case have a look at [Defining N-ary Relations on the Semantic Web](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/), by which you might end up with data like `[] hasSubject personA ; hasLocation roomA ; atTime noon .`.

Comment: Finally, please read the tag descriptions before posting;  this question has nothing to do with "The Apache HTTP Server, commonly referred to as Apache, ... an open-source HTTP server".  I've removed the tag.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thx a lot for your answer! Would you be so kind to give a specific example how to implement an `n-ary relation` in `jena`, because I thought a quadruple can be implemented by a quad? Or is `quad` not the right data structure for my problem?

Comment: may i drop in this conversation (i'm a colleague of Vivien). we know that a quad (in jena) is used for storing triples in named graphs. our  idea is to "abuse" this feature, to attach a timestamp to triples. i don't know if this is practical (i.e., does it come with an overhead?), but we just wanted to give it a try.

basically what we would like to do is something like this:
`RdfQuadruple q = new RdfQuadruple(subject, predicate, object, timestamp)`

we were thinking about ways this could be done in jena without using blank nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing triples or quads individually is very unusual. Jena's api normally deals with collections of such items, such as `Graph`, or more pertinently for your case [`DatasetGraph`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/sparql/core/DatasetGraph.html), or even simply java collections.

Jena's output is usually handled via [`RDFDataMgr`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/riot/RDFDataMgr.html). There are a couple of options here:

1. The very simple [`RDFDataMgr.writeQuads(OutputStream out, Iterator<Quad> iterator)`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/riot/RDFDataMgr.html#writeQuads(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.util.Iterator)), which only writes N-Quads.
2. The more general [`RDFDataMgr.write(OutputStream out, DatasetGraph dataset, Lang lang)`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/riot/RDFDataMgr.html#write(java.io.OutputStream,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.core.DatasetGraph,%20org.apache.jena.riot.Lang)) which supports a number of formats.

The former is as simple to invoke as this (targeting standard out in this case):

```
RDFDataMgr.writeQuads(System.out, Collections.singleton(q).iterator());
```

The latter is more involved:

```
DatasetGraph dsg = new DatasetGraphSimpleMem(); // very simple implementation
dsg.add(q);
RDFDataMgr.write(System.out, dsg, Lang.TRIG); // or NQUADS
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! As I understand it, you suggest to add the `quad` to a `DatasetGraph`. However, I was wondering if this is the best way to solve my problem, because basically I have a fourth property which I would like to add to my basic subject, prädicat and object triple? The thing why I want to do that is that I will use this data as a stream and do some reasoning on my data and ask questions like `Which person is in Room A at time t?`(as shown by my example above)

Answer (score 0):

I believe Blank Nodes cannot be avoided when representing timeseries :: a list of (timestamp, value) for a particular measure or sensor.
RDF was not originally designed to represent timeseries, of course we can, but it comes with the extra cost of the blank node for every measure.

A 
       hasTimeStamp ts1,
       hasValue v1
       hasTimeStamp ts2,
       hasValue v2

@mrquad I m not sure if you managed to represent what you wanted.